# $\mathbf{Z}_2$-oriented vs $\mathbf{Z}_2$- orientable?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

On the Wikipedia page of [Fundamental class and Stiefel-Whitney class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_class) :

> If ''M'' is not orientable,  $H_n(M,\mathbf{Z}) \ncong \mathbf{Z}$, and so one cannot define a fundamental class ''M'' living inside the integers. However, every closed manifold is $\mathbf{Z}_2$-orientable, and
> $H_n(M,\mathbf{Z}_2)=\mathbf{Z}_2$ (for ''M'' connected). Thus every closed manifold is $\mathbf{Z}_2$-oriented (not just orient''able'': there is no ambiguity in choice of orientation), and has a $\mathbf{Z}_2$-fundamental class. This $\mathbf{Z}_2$-fundamental class is used in defining  Stiefel–Whitney class.

My question is that:

1. What distinguish the $\mathbf{Z}_2$-oriented  and orientable? Am I correct to say that we can have unorientable surfaces ($\mathbb{RP}^n$ for even $n$) but they are still $\mathbf{Z}_2$-oriented? Please helps clarifying this point.
2. "This $\mathbf{Z}_2$-fundamental class is used in defining  Stiefel–Whitney class."
   Isn't that all the $j$-th $\mathbf{Z}_2$-homology class give rise to all the $j$-th Stiefel–Whitney class for $1 \leq j \leq n$?

- then what is the emphasis of $\mathbf{Z}_2$-fundamental class? (the $n$-th $\mathbf{Z}_2$-homology class here)
- how do we know whether the   $j$-th cohomology class
  $H^j(M,\mathbf{Z}_2) $ is the   $j$-th Stiefel–Whitney class but not other  cohomology classes? (arent there other possible choices?)

Comment: Looking through the [edit history of the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Fundamental_class&oldid=652818725), it seems the correct sentence should be "This $\mathbb{Z}_2$-fundamental class is used in defining Stiefel-Whitney *numbers*."  Maybe a Wikipedian can help fix this.

Comment: anyone can edit Wikipedia. You can edit too, please!

Comment: The point for your first question is that over $\mathbb Z$, there *is* a difference between orientable and oriented, because on an orientable manifold there are two choices of generator of $H_n(M,\mathbb Z) \cong \mathbb Z$, namely the elements corresponding to $1$ and $-1$. But a group isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z$ has only a single choice of generator, so there is no ambiguity.

Comment: This is a reasonable question which does not deserve to be downvoted.

Comment: For your second point: Stiefel-Whitney classes are classes defined on a manifold with a vector bundle (its tangent bundle by default), and they carry information on this vector bundle. A priori, any mod 2 cohomology class in a manifold is not necessarily a combination of S.W. classes. Some manifolds have vanishing S.W. classes in each degree, like parallelisable manifolds.